# Relatively new to Linux

Tags: performance

While I've tinkered with Linux in the past, I have become fed up with Apple, and I dislike Windows very much. So, now I'm getting serious about changing over. I've already posted my 1st question, but have more. I'm fairly comfortable using terminal since I started in the 90s using DOS. But that's been awhile and I need to find good tutorials on the basics of Linux Ubuntu. I've installed a few programs, and so far, all are working as they should, except for OBS. Anyway,if you could point me in the right direction for good tutorials, it would be much appreciated! TIA

db

Comment: You are aware this is a Q&A site that has more strict rules than a forum will have. https://ubuntuforums.org/ being the address of Ubuntu Forums. A Q&A site requires you to identify your actual problem to be solved (ie. question) that is then answered with alternative ways of solving it. I don't read "*point me in the right direction for good tutorials*" as being a *problem to be solved* (https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask) fitting the rules of this Q&A site, yet that question would be great on a forum (*even probably encouraged!*).  We all want people to learn, but best in the right place.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: FYI:  I'd wait to see if my *view* gets an upvote, or the another comment before I'd close/delete the question.. You may get some responses from others anyway (*I tend to be more legalistic than others; though I did upvote your other question as I felt that was appropriate for a newbie question!*).  The obvious tutorial link for Ubuntu is https://ubuntu.com/tutorials  but any search engine would have found you that anyway.

Comment: It's unclear to me if you are looking for general advice (about what?), or if you have specific questions about OBS.

Comment: Just general advice.  I'm finding quite a bit of tutorials so I guess I'm good for now.
Thanks much!